# TFS 2010 (Team Explorer) - Default split view for work items query results window

Tags: visual-studio-2010, team-explorer

I work with Visual Studio 2010 to access information on a TFS 2010 instance.

I've got my work items queries, and when I double-click them the results are shown (of course). The default view is the horizontal split (list of the work items on top, and the details of the selected one below). However, I prefer the vertical split view (list of the work items on the left, and the details of the selected on the right).

I can change the split view easily, but I need to do it every time I open the results window. Is there any way to configure this windows to open with the vertical split by default?

Comment: The same with folder/flat view in pending changes window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fabio,

It is not possible to configure this, nor do we have any setting to support this. If you feel that this is important and we should put this in VS vNext, then you can post you suggestion at [User Voice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com).

Ewald Hofman
TFS Program Manager

Comment: Thanks, Ewald, I've done what you suggested (https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2535564-configure-defaults-for-views-in-tfs-windows). Hope other people find it interesting enough to put in the next team explorer version.